# idleConnectionTimeout in Gremlin driver

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I have an application running on my localhost (which the gremlin driver runs on), a gremlin server running on the remote host, and a load balancer in between.

I have setup the keepAliveInterval of the Gremlin driver to keep the connection between my localhost and the load balancer open, but somehow the connection still get dropped. (The timeout interval in the load balancer is larger than the keepAliveInterval I configured in Gremlin driver).

I checked the log and find out that after connection get dropped, the Gremlin driver is still sending keep alive message to the load balancer, but it didn't get any response and it couldn't detect it as well.

I'm wondering are there any ways I can find out the keep alive response isn't been received or are there some configurations I can do like the IdleConnectionTimeout in the Gremlin server to let the gremlin driver realize the keep alive request is not getting any response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver's keep-alive process is not terribly robust as it's a bit of a redundancy for the server-side keep-alive. The driver swallows exceptions related to the sending of it's own keep-alive messages and will only log a `WARN` message, so you would have to find the message in the log to determine if there was failure.

I'm not sure what gets your environment into a state where the load balancer loses the connection. Both the server and driver work together to maintain the connection. When the driver is idle it will send a keep-alive after the `keepAliveInterval` is exceeded which should reset idle state for both driver and server. On the server, the read and write idle state is monitored (by `idleConnectionTimeout` and `keepAliveInterval` respectively) and will send a keep-alive to the client. From either end of the "ping" (server or client) a "pong" should be returned. I wonder if there is a state of the load balancer that kills the connection if the "ping" doesn't come from the client-side?

Comment: Hmm, there's no WARN message in my log, I think the keep-alive request sent by the Gremlin driver is succeed but I don't know where the connection get dropped, it could be between the client and LB as well as the LB and target. We didn't setup the keepAliveInterval in the Gremlin server, because I wonder since there's already heartbeat checking exist between the LB and the target, which also thru the traffic port (in this case it is the 8192 port for write instance, 8193 for read instance). continued on the next comment...

Comment: I'm wondering since the heartbeat is also checked through the 8192 port, there shouldn't be necessary to setup the keep-alive in the Gremlin server again? The connection between the Gremlin server and the LB shouldn't be dropped by the LB, right?

Comment: how is the LB doing keep-alive to Gremlin Server? is it sending a websocket ping somehow? if you've disabled Gremlin Server keep-alive, perhaps you should reconsider. Try turning off the LB native keep-alive and just let the Gremlin driver and server do their keep-alive activity through the LB to see if that fixes things.

Comment: hmm.. the LB is just forwarding the package between client and target. The disconnection get reproduced yesterday and I captured the tcp traffic this time and find out before the connection get lost, there's a FIN package sent from the LB to client. I'm wondering why wouldn't the ping/pong msg throw an exception after the connection got cut? In the driver it's using the same old connection for the keep-alive msg right? Wouldn't the TCP buffer get fulled after the connection get cut off?

Comment: And btw.. under what situation would the Gremlin server send a FIN package to the client? I'm wondering the FIN package could be sent from target instead of the LB.